# A better pattern for Django form logic?

Tags: django, django-forms

The standard pattern for the view logic for Django forms is thus:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('contact.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

This is fine in simple cases but quite easily descends into a complex mass of nested IF statements if your application logic gets a bit more complex.

Can anyone share their own cleaner approaches that avoid nested IF's and logic that depends on fall-through cases?

I'd be particularly interested in answers that don't rely on additional 3rd party apps.

Answer (score 12):

One of the included class based views is `FormView` ([documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#editing-views)). The two main methods you'd be concerned with are `form_valid` and `form_invalid`.

```
from django.views.generic import FormView

from myapp.forms import MyForm

class MyView(FormView):

    template_name = 'edit_something.html'
    form_class = MyForm
    success_url = '/success/' # you should use `reverse`, but let's stay focused.

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        This is what's called when the form is valid.
        """

        return super(MyView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        """
        This is what's called when the form is invalid.
        """

        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Alternatively you can override `post`, `get` or `put` methods and handle the form according to each type of request.

Comment: I don't think my specific case fits any of the existing classes too neatly but reading their source is going to be a great inspiration for a better structure...

Comment: What's your specific case? I'm finding the provided classes offer a lot and the trick is to mix and match various ones to get a desired result and making any extensions is minimal/easy.

Comment: Using reverse in the success_url definition has caused me some problems, especially when the views.py is imported before the urlconf is defined

Comment: Instead of directly doing `returning HttpResponseRedirect()` in your version, you should instead use `return super(MyView, self).form_valid(form)` at the tail end of your `form_valid()` and `form_invalid()`. This will do your operations upon the data before then running Django's version of form_valid() on it as well (which does nothing but return the redirect). This way, if Django ever changes what happens inside of form_valid(), you haven't completely removed it.

Comment: @synic: use reverse_lazy() instead of reverse().

Answer (score 3):

This is shortest approach I found:

```
def contact(request):
    # if it's POST request it'll have data else it'll  be unbound
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        # ...
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST

    return render_to_response('contact.html', { 'form': form, })
```

of course if you don't like nested if you could try reversing logic:

```
def contact(request):
    template = 'contact.html'
    if request.method != 'POST': # GET return:
        return render_to_response(template, {'form': ContactForm()})

    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if not form.is_valid(): # FAIL return:
        return render_to_response(template, {'form': form})

    # here logic if user posted form and it's clean:

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

Comment: upvoted - your first example is the nicest way to do forms in a Django view I think. Note that you don't need the `if request.method == 'POST'` check though... the form can't be valid if you've passed `None` to the constructor, this is the same as doing `ContactForm()`

Answer (score 2):

For complex scenarios, you should really consider overriding various methods of your form class which are involved in the validation/sanitizing process. The `BaseForm` class defines a `_post_clean()` method with no behavior which is particularly meant to be overridden. Overriding `_clean()` properly is also pretty straight forward, you could do that too if you wanted to do something before `clean()` is called.

Reading the source of `django.forms` will give you a much clearer insight on how the forms work and discover the right pattern for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i tried so far to make view funcs cleaner:

- Separate view functions for GET / POST

  Obviously is_valid logic in  form as state in prev post.

  Overriding model save() method to make if form.is_valid() part cleaner ( you can hide other related objects creates inside one save() )

  Move common parts of view-funcs code into separeate function.

  Also if your GET part is not CPU or database intense you can do it above if req == POST..
  in other words do it always..   
  I for example often do: ctx['form'] = ContactForm() at the top.. and then again 
  ContactForm(req.POST) inside if req == POST

**BUT**
django 1.3 Now have class based view.. And this give one a big opportunity
to make view extendable.. to make mixins.. not to write the save over and over.
I personally want to give it a shot and will try write django stuff in a new style with classes.

Comment: I'd be interested to see a class based version of the standard form handling logic. 

Also - could you elaborate on your third bullet point?

Comment: Often in form.is_valid(): goes something like this: my_obj = form.save( commit = False ); my_obj.some_attr = datetime.now(); OtherObj = OtherModel( my_obj = my_obj, ... ); If this is common operation.. or just for beauty you can hide all this stuff in MyModel.save() or MyModel.custom_save()

Answer (score 1):

The main source of complexity in these cases is handling GETs and POSTs in the same view function. Separate the logic for each method into its own view and things become clearer.

The only duplication will be rendering the form html, but that particular part is concise and meaningful for both cases (i.e. not boilerplate), so that's acceptable.